# Codec and setting for lowest bitrate ffmpeg output

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, android, mp3

I need to convert my input audio file to the lowest possible size to transfer it over a radio transmitter.

Now with the AAC codec and MP3 format I used 8kbps for bit rate, 16 kHz for sampling rate and 1 channel, and my output data is about 3kb per second.

But when I change the sample rate to 8 kHz or a lower bit rate, I get an error saying that the codec does not support this setting.

Is there a setting to get lower rate for the output file?

P.S: Because I'm working on Android, it's hard to install codecs, so I must use the ffmpeg default codecs.

**Update:**

i used opus command line now
this is my command:

```
ffmpeg -i a.mp3 -vn -c:a libopus -ac 1 -ar 8000 -b:a 500 -vbr constrained -compression_level 0 -application lowdelay output22.mkv
```

and the result is

```
Input #0, mp3, from 'a.mp3':
  Metadata:
    title           : Salam (myahangha.ir)
    artist          : Sogand
    album           : Javooni
    comment         : ..:: myahangha.ir ::..
    genre           : 2019
    date            : 2019
  Duration: 00:03:15.24, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 324 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 320 kb/s
    Stream #0:1: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj420p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 500x500 [SAR 72:72 DAR 1:1], 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Metadata:
      title           : Radio Javan - Javooni.jpg
      comment         : Other
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (mp3 (mp3float) -> opus (libopus))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libopus @ 0000028b84d9e200] Bitrate 500 is extremely low, maybe you mean 500k
The bitrate parameter is set too low. It takes bits/s as argument, not kbits/s
Output #0, matroska, to 'output24.mkv':
  Metadata:
    title           : Salam (myahangha.ir)
    artist          : Sogand
    album           : Javooni
    comment         : ..:: myahangha.ir ::..
    genre           : 2019
    date            : 2019
    encoder         : Lavf58.27.102
    Stream #0:0: Audio: opus (libopus) ([255][255][255][255] / 0xFFFFFFFF), 8000 Hz, mono, flt, 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.51.100 libopus
size=     116kB time=00:03:15.25 bitrate=   4.9kbits/s speed= 396x
video:0kB audio:57kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 103.282921%
```

it seems opus dont accept bit rates lower then 4.9kbps :(

Comment: I've edited your post to add "kHz" to sampling rate. I assumed you meant that. Or do you mean bits per sample?

Comment: Also, could you clarify if you mean "_3 kb/s (kilobits / sec)_", or "_3 kB/s (kiloBytes / sec)_"

Comment: Who is @roozgar and why is he or she clarifiying your post for you?

Comment: no problem, we are working together on this project :)

Comment: I see. Next time when asking about ffmpeg, please include the specific command(s) that you were trying and any command-line output that you got (including errors).

Comment: @slhck i added the command and result , thank you

Comment: 4.9 kBit/s is really not much. You should be looking into AMR-NB.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

AAC or MP3 are not the best choice of codecs for ultra-low bandwidth transmissions. Use a proper *speech* codec with higher efficiency.

Opus is the best option. It is available in FFmpeg through [`libopus`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#libopus-1). In fact, Opus is not just made for speech; it offers hybrid encoding for *both* speech and music.

Example:

```
ffmpeg -i <input> -c:a libopus -ac 1 -ar 16000 -b:a 8K -vbr constrained out.opus
```

Here, `-ac` sets the output to mono, `-ar` sets the sampling rate to 16 kHz, and `-b:a` sets the bitrate to 8 kBit/s. The constrained variable bitrate mode is used here. In principle, it's not strictly necessary to downsample and downmix to mono with `ffmpeg`, as that is something `libopus` will do on its own to reach the specified bitrate target.

Some further recommendations are given [here](https://wiki.xiph.org/index.php?title=Opus_Recommended_Settings&mobileaction=toggle_view_desktop). Note that with Opus, 6–8 kBit/s is usable range for (mono, lower sample rate) speech, but not for music.

You'll find an interesting comparison of different codecs and their bitrate/quality curve on [the Opus website](http://opus-codec.org/comparison/):

[image]

I should add that this figure is an indication only; it's compiled from different test results and anecdotal knowledge.

Comment: thank you, i will try `HE-AAC v2` or `libopus` but how about if i use default ffmpeg codecs ?!

Comment: Please read my answer again: you should not use AAC, but Opus. There's no proper Opus support for lower bitrates built into ffmpeg. Same for other speech codecs like [AMR-NB](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html#libopencore_002damrnb-1). You need to compile ffmpeg with these options. It's possible to do that for Android. See: https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg

Comment: thank you,but is the output of this coded is `.opus` and it need a specific player to play sounds؟

Comment: It needs a player that can decode Opus, yes.